How to handle "chunked" content-encoding in Flutter using Dio?
I can't find anything online that explains the correct way of handling "chunked" API responses in Flutter Dio.
I am working on a Flutter application that uses Dio to connect to an API and receive a JSON text. I started working and testing on a local instance of the API and everything was well until it was time to deploy the API to a remote server. I started getting this error in from Dio on some requests:
DioException [unknown]: null
Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
!  ���|�?$k��&$e�����xH9�������1C:��)� a��-&I�ćg$���,5j]���1�ơk����...
^

Although these same requests work perfectly in Postman. After some digging, I found out there was a new value in the header of the requests that don't work, this new value was Transfer-Encoding: "chunked".
I tried setting dio.options.responseType= ResponseType.bytes and that worked until I tried to decode the response body.
What should I do to either receive the JSON correctly or decode the response bytes?
